# elasticsearch ingest processing zip

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I've installed the `ingest-attachment` plugin to elasticsearch successfully. It's working with base64-ed text files and pdfs, but when I've added a zip (containing a plain json text file), the data inserted to the given index, but `attachment.content` doesn't exist (which the pdf and text file has). `attachment.content_type` has the value `zip`, so it knows what type the content is.

Is `ingest-attachment` somehow capable of making contents of a zip file searchable?